# I can't set a value to a array on JS - TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

When I run the code, works fine for the first time(array[0]). The problem isn't at the function MatFin.ativos.covariancia. Can somebody help me?

The error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

```js
function matrizDeCovariancia(ativos) {
  i = 0
  var matrizResultado = new Array
  while (i < Object.keys(ativos).length) {
    matrizResultado[i] = new Array
    a = 0
    while (a < Object.keys(ativos).length) {
      matrizResultado[i][a] = MatFin.ativos.covariancia(ativos[i], ativos[a])
      a++
    }
    i++
  }
  return matrizResultado
}
```

Comment: If it isn't at that line, where is it?

Comment: There is no promise in your code so we cannot tell

Comment: How is `matrizDeCovariancia` called? [Edit] your post and include a [mre]. Currently, your code only defines a function and does nothing else, so there is no TypeError to be thrown. `matrizDeCovariancia()` would produce a similar TypeError. So, how is the error produced?

Comment: The fact you do not declare your variables, I would not be surprised if it is related to that. Probably reused `i` or `a` in other parts of your code and it updates and causes the error. Declare your variables with var, let, const

Comment: I agree with @epascarello I'll bet `MatFin.ativos.covariancia()` also has an undeclared variable `i` or `a`, so it's modifying your variables.

Comment: If `ativos` is an object, and `i` is an integer, then `ativos[i]` is likely going to be undefined.  Maybe you meant `ativos[Object.keys(ativos)[i]]`?  (same with ativos[a])

Comment: FWIW, I believe `new Array` should be `new Array()`

Comment: @user1599011 These two are equivalent, but `[]` is preferrable over both of these.